# How can i change position of the cursor in windows console in java

Tags: java, console, cursor, position

I want when the user enter your number 
 number for example write in the position x=55 y=45

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: im beginner in java program and now i start learn java i see the reference book in java such as deitel and i dont see any answer because in c# be console.clear(); for clear console and i want that code can do the same action in java

Comment: By the way, that's not how Java works. Note that the console handled by C#/.net is directly the Windows console, while Java uses InputStream to communicate with the console, thus not having all the *powers* you have on .Net.

Comment: my code is 
package javaapplication16;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaApplication16 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input=new Scanner (in);
            int a,b,c;
            out.print("Please Enter Your First number : ");
            a = input.nextInt();                           
           // I want the console clear here             out.print("PLease Enter Your Second Number : ");
            b = input.nextInt();
            c = a + b;
            out.printf("Sum is %d",c);

Answer (score 0):

[This post has the same Q and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941324/how-do-i-set-the-position-of-the-mouse-in-java)

Theres a class called ROBOT in java which controls the peripherals of the pc, check it out .

[Link to ROBOT class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)

[Tutorial on mouse moving using ROBOT](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-se-api-tutorials/214-java-program-contol-computer-mouse-using-awt-robot-events.html)

the main code from the tutorial above :

```
import java.awt.Robot;
public class MouseClass {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
Robot robot = new Robot();
 // SET THE MOUSE X Y POSITION
 robot.mouseMove(300, 550);
}
```