# How to control (move) the mouse cursor?

Tags: java, mouse-cursor

How do I move the mouse cursor (windows) with Java?
I have a pair of values constantly being updated. I want to use them to control the cursor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set the position of the mouse in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941324/how-do-i-set-the-position-of-the-mouse-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Robot.mouseMove(x,y)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#mouseMove%28int,%20int%29)

As mentioned in:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2941373/1150918 by [OscarRyz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20654/oscarryz).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the Robot class.

```
Robot r = null;
try {
    r = new Robot();
} catch (AWTException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
r.mouseMove(x, y);//x is the horizontal position on the screen, y is the vertical
```