# how to place mouse directly above a JOptionPane button in java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, joptionpane

As a button can be preselected to be hit by Enter key , is there an way to place mouse on a selected button of Joption pane Button ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question was initially closed as a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941324/how-do-i-set-the-position-of-the-mouse-in-java. While you indeed might use a Robot to position the mouse on a component,  the big issue is how to get the location of the component?. A JOptionPane is a modal dialog and you can't access the buttons directly so you don't know the location of the buttons. I reopened the question for other suggestions.

Comment: I have never tried it before but you might: 1) Read the JOptionPane API. The section on "Direct Use" shows how to create a JOptionPane panel and add it to a dialog. 2) Then you would pack the dialog so all components have a size. 3) Use the `getRootPane()` method of the dialog. 4) Use the `getDefaultButton()` method of the root pane. 5) Use the Robot from the above link to position the mouse cursor. 6) Make the dialog visible.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I did it.
First, create an instance of [JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)

```java
JOptionPane oPane = new JOptionPane();
```

Then create the [dialog](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JDialog.html) and display it.

```java
JDialog dlg = oPane.createDialog("Dialog Title");
dlg.setVisible(true);
```

This is a screen capture of the displayed dialog.

[image: default dialog]

I did some experimenting and discovered that the `JOptionPane` instance contains two child components.

```java
Component[] cmpts = oPane.getComponents();
for (Component cmpt : cmpts) {
    System.out.println(cmpt.getClass());
}
```

Each child is a [JPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JPanel.html). One of them contains the **OK** [JButton](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JButton.html).

Then I added a [WindowListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) to the `JDialog`. When the `JDialog` is displayed for the first time, I use a [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Robot.html) to move the mouse pointer to the **OK** button.

```java
javax.swing.JOptionPane oPane = new javax.swing.JOptionPane();
javax.swing.JDialog dlg = oPane.createDialog("Dialog Title");
dlg.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent wndEvt) {
        javax.swing.JComponent jCmpt = (javax.swing.JComponent) oPane.getComponent(1);
        javax.swing.JButton button = (javax.swing.JButton) jCmpt.getComponent(0);
        java.awt.Point pt = button.getLocationOnScreen();
        try {
            java.awt.Robot robbie = new java.awt.Robot();
            robbie.mouseMove(pt.x, pt.y);
        }
        catch (java.awt.AWTException xAwt) {
            xAwt.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
dlg.setVisible(true);
```

Note that the above is simply a [proof of concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_concept) (POC). I suggest that you investigate the API of the classes appearing in the above code in order to make it suitable for your requirements.

Comment: Using a `WindowListener` is more elegant than the solution I used (a non-modal dialog)

Answer (score 1):

The following is an mre demonstrating placing the mouse over `JOptionPane` button:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MouseOverJOptionPaneButton {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane();
        optionPane.setMessage("Mouse positioned over the button");
        optionPane.setMessageType(JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        JButton jButton = new JButton("OK");
        jButton.addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
            System.out.println(jButton.getText() +" pressed");
        });
        optionPane.setOptions(new Object[] { jButton });
        JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("");
        //if modal, placeMouseOver is invoked after dialog closes
        //alternatively use WindowListener as in Arba's answer
        dialog.setModal(false);  
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        placeMouseOver(jButton);
        //todo, optionally:  dialog.setModal(true);
    }

    private static void placeMouseOver(JComponent comp) {
        try {
            //calculate center of component AFTER it is showing
            int xCoord = comp.getLocationOnScreen().x + comp.getWidth()/2;
            int yCoord = comp.getLocationOnScreen().y + comp.getHeight()/2;
            // Move the cursor
            new Robot().mouseMove(xCoord, yCoord);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```